# AWS | MWAA Dependency in private repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I am trying to read up on AWS' MWAA service. We run a moderately small number of ETL processes, but we are looking to expand in the near future, and I am trying to get out of having to manage our current Airflow production environment.

The question I have is simple: has anyone been able to install Python dependencies via `requirements.txt` that are hosted in *private* repos on say GitHub? I am guessing there would have to be a way to pass in an authentication token to the requirements file somehow.

An immediate work around (perhaps ugly) is to make copies of the repos somewhere in AWS? Maybe S3?

I appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested way is to build the private repo as a whl, then place that whl in the Airflow MWAA plugins.zip.

Comment: What is the source of this suggested way?

Comment: Here is one source describing the process https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/mwaa-environment-install-libraries

Answer (score -3):

> The question I have is simple: has anyone been able to install Python dependencies via requirements.txt that are hosted in private repos on say GitHub?

This method for hosting `requirements.txt` is not supported.

> An immediate work around (perhaps ugly) is to make copies of the repos somewhere in AWS? Maybe S3?

To be clear, this approach is not considered a "workaround". It is the only supported method for hosting `requirements.txt`. DAG files and `requirements.txt` must be stored in S3. Source control platforms like GitHub provide tools like GitHub Actions for automating CI/CD actions, such as copying source files to S3.

References

1. [Create an Amazon S3 bucket for Amazon MWAA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-s3-bucket.html)